# How to load a redux store asynchronously without breaking the app where redux Connect is used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

The reasons I want to do such a thing is so I can import the store outside my main bundle as the firebase middleware and firestore are crazy big and are slowing first paint.

Index.js

```
const store = async () =>  createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {
      userProfile: "users",
      useFirestoreForProfile: true,
      attachAuthIsReady: true
    }),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig), // redux bindings for firestore
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
  registerServiceWorker();
```

Other components that rely on the store:

```
...
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HeaderRight);
```

Error:

```
The above error occurred in the <Connect(Form(SignIn))> component:
```